# How can I use the Google App engine bulkloader to back up all my data?

Tags: google-app-engine, backup, bulkloader

The [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data) say

```
appcfg.py --dump --app_id=<app-id> \
 --url=http://<appname>.appspot.com/remote_api \
 --filename=<data-filename>
```

The thing itself barfs:

```
Usage: appcfg.py [options] <action>
appcfg.py: error: no such option: --dump
$ cat /usr/local/share/google_appengine/VERSION 
release: "1.3.4"
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I had to use download_data instead of --dump and --application instead of --app_id, for example:

```
 appcfg.py download_data --application=app_id --url=http://etc --filename=file
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that you have two versions of app engine installed; one on your python path (a different version of appengine) and one in the /usr/local/share/google_appengine/VERSION directory (which reports 1.3.4)