# appcfg.py: error: no such option: --dump on google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use the Google App engine bulkloader to back up all my data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946371/how-can-i-use-the-google-app-engine-bulkloader-to-back-up-all-my-data)

i follow this article :http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

and want to download all data from my app ,

but when i use the next code,it show error:

```
D:\zjm_demo\app>appcfg.py --dump --app_id=zjm1126 --url=http://zjm1126.appspot.c
om/remote_api --filename=a.csv
Usage: appcfg.py [options] <action>

appcfg.py: error: no such option: --dump
```

why ?

thanks

**updated**

i use this :

```
appcfg.py download_data  --application=zjm1126 --url=http://zjm1126.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=a.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation appears to be incorrect:

I found that I had to use download_data instead of --dump and --application instead of --app_id, for example:

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=app_id --url=http://etc --filename=file
```

This is a duplicate of [How can I use the Google App engine bulkloader to back up all my data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946371/how-can-i-use-the-google-app-engine-bulkloader-to-back-up-all-my-data)

Comment: Did you set up remote_api as described at http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Setting_Up_remote_api ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a "why" answer, but it looks to me like you'll want to use the `download_data` action instead.

```
> appcfg help download_data
Usage: appcfg.py [options] download_data <directory>

Download entities from datastore.

The 'download_data' command downloads datastore entities and writes them to
file as CSV or developer defined format.

...
```

You may want to read the [Configuring the Bulk Loader](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuring_the_Bulk_Loader) section for more information. I've never had a need to download my data, so I've no real experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

use appcfg.py download_data "Application Directory / --app_id" --config_file=etc.yaml --kind=etc --filename=etc.csv